# Downloading CSV from Google Sheet, and importing as contacts in MacOS - issue with foreign characters

Tags: macos, csv, google-sheets, import-contacts

I'm working in a Google Sheet where I have contact information of the business. I also have another sheet where I have copied the information into CSV-friendly format.

When I download as CSV and import in MacOS contacts, my foreign characters don't play along.

Ø becomes "√∏"
Æ becomes "√¶"
Å becomes "√•"

Any idea to fix this? When Googling the issue all is pointing to "Unicode-8", but as far as I know Google automatically downloads as "Unicode-8".

In advance, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are encountering is related to the **MacOS Contacts Encoding** and not to the Google CSV since Google Sheets exports to CSV using the `UTF-8 encoding`.

Therefore, in order to fix your issue, you should access [this link](https://support.apple.com/guide/contacts/import-contacts-from-other-apps-adrbk1457/mac) and follow the steps shown in the **Import from other file types** section.